# What is the name of the sauce served with fried rice in Indian restaurants

Tags: sauce, indian-cuisine

I have noticed a lighter sauce like liquid (watery) with green chilies cut in it served along with fried rice in Indian restaurants. It tastes slightly like soya, and has visible round pieces of cut green chilies in it. (It's definitely not mint chutney.)

Does anyone know the name of that sauce?

Comment: Wouldn't just asking the server be an option? Then you might have at least a "sounds like XY" name...

Comment: It could be just about anything from a cucumber sauce to chili water.

Comment: What colour was the sauce? Was it it sour, sweet, hot, etc?

Comment: After seeing two so wildly different answers which both fit the original description, I realized that the question is too vague. This is just the situation this close reason is supposed to prevent: well meaning people taking shots in the dark. If you edit the question with an exact description, it can be reopened. But for now, it could be anything.

Comment: @rumtscho I think from his original description (liquid like water with the green chilies) and his follow up comment (that it is not mint and tastes slightly like soya with another reference to the chilies), that my answer is at least tracking in the right direction. I will wait to see if we get a response back from the OP but I would like to see it reopened so that others who may have more info can weigh in.

Comment: @Cindy You could well be right, but I think rumtscho was right to close. The only person with more info is the OP; others who weigh in won't have more info, they'll just be making more well-intentioned guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the sauce you are looking for may be **Nam Prik Nam Pla**, pictured below.

[image]

The basic recipe is simply sliced birds' eye chilies soaked in fish sauce. Some recipes call for both red and green chilies. Other recipes call for other ingredients such as lime juice, sugar or brown sugar, garlic, shallots, etc.

**EDIT** Still haven't found anything with Indian origins, but here is a picture of a Malaysian variation, which is birds' eye chilis marinated in soy sauce.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it matches the description except that it was in an Indian restaurant and this is Thai.

Comment: @Sobachatina  Yes, but with the proximity of Thailand to India, it is quite possible that the sauces used may be the same or very similar. This sauce is pretty much a staple and is served with many dishes, including fried rice.

Comment: It could be a tamarind based sauce if it was Indian.

Comment: Hey, this one was the sauce I referred to. I had this when I was in Kerala(South India).  They call it as 'vinegar - soy - chilli sauce'

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would say this question is too vague- however a common sauce, found in practically every Indian restaurant, fits that description.

Mint chutney:

[image]

It is basically mint leaves and peppers blended with garlic, lemon and seasonings.

It is ubiquitous in Indian cuisine (in several regions) and every Indian restaurant I have been to.

Comment: It is not mint. . It tastes slightly like soya and I can found round shape cut green chillies in that.  It usually serves with fried rice